# UIButton with custom shadow image

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, uikit, uibutton

I need to achieve effect of my button like this:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How can I add this custom shadow to button, so only 'BUTTON' surface reacts for touches?
2. When I have the next button in the bottom, close to previous one, how can I be sure that it will not be covered by upper's button shadow? 
   I need to have all the buttons in front and all the shadows in the back.

Comment: http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths

Comment: Thanks endy, this is a way of drawing simple shapes, which can be useful in my example. This solves the problem for simple shapes, but I want to make this question further to complex ones. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to add the shadow without having it clickable, you need to add an imageView to as a subview to the button. (make sure clip subviews is disabled).
2. If you want the shadow of one button not appearing on top of the other, then you need to have the shadow(s) added separately to the main parent view. The solution in option 1 will not work. Its not neat, but its the only way i can think off.